# Bijective function from $\Bbb Z^+$ to $\Bbb Z\backslash \{-1,0,1\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am supposed to give a bijective function from $\Bbb Z^+$ to $\Bbb Z\backslash \{-1,0,1\}$, where $\Bbb Z^+$ is the set of positive integers and $\Bbb Z$ is the set of integers. I don't quite understand how a set with a smaller size can be surjective when mapped to a set with a larger size; wouldn't there be too many elements to map to? Can anyone help explain the problem and potentially provide a function that meets the criteria?

Comment: You are right that a set of a smaller "size" cannot be surjectively mapped to a set with a larger "size". Yet, here, a bijection does exist. So, perhaps, these set are of the same "size". Infinity is weird, as you are finding out.

Comment: This won't solve your problem but it might help your intuition.  The even natural numbers *seem* to be smaller than the natural numbers, but the function $f(x)=\frac x2$ maps the even natural numbers surjectively onto $\Bbb N$.

Comment: I figured it has something to do with the infinite size but I still couldn't think of a function to map for example 1 to 1, 2 to -1, 3 to 2 etc.

Comment: How would you systematically list the elements of $\Bbb Z \setminus \{-1, 0, 1 \}$?

Comment: Logically I wanted to do something like 2, -2, 3, -3, etc. but I couldn't think of a function that would do that.

Comment: try $f(x)=(-1)^x(\lceil\frac{x}{2}\rceil+1)$. The key is to wind around the range in such a way that you don't try to map to infinity before you map to any finite value. In this case, that means hitting both positive and negative values, while increasing (more slowly) in magnitude.

Comment: @Prometheus does that function hit $-2,3,-4,...$?

Comment: How about $f\left(x\right)=\operatorname{ceil}\left(\frac{x+2}{2}\right)\cos\left(\pi x\right)$?

Comment: Isn't that equal to the ceiling of x/2+1?

Comment: Yes it is, I just wrote like that to make it one single fractional term

Comment: Ah, I was trying to figure out why it was an injection, I completely forgot about the cosine, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what someone in the comments section said about the output forming a sequence like $2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, ...$, I came up with the following function:

$f(n)=\left\lceil{\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}\right\rceil\cos\left(\pi n\right)$

Graphically, it would look like this:

[image: Desmos graph]

Comment: A nice example: this isn't a bijection on $\mathbb{R}$, but it sure is on $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: It works very nicely, I just have no clue how to operate on it algebraically, do you have a recommendation as to how to prove it is bijective? For injectivity, I normally set f(x)=f(y) and try to solve for x=y but I can't figure out how to do that with this one

Comment: Yep, which is pretty neat :)

Comment: @GS1221 For $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ to share the same sign, $x$ and $y$ must give the same remainder when modulus 2 is applied. That takes care of the cosine. Substitute this finding into the ceiling expression with $n=2k+a$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a=0,1$.

Comment: I mean, since it's defined on a subset of $\mathbb Z$, is should graphically just be the labeled points, no curve. In fact, the curve sort of intuitively detracts from the injectivitity of $f$.

Comment: Okay, I finished that proof. Now I just need to worry about surjectivity. Again, I don't know how to algebraically work with the ceiling function, can I just ignore it and try to solve for x?

Comment: I'd suggest breaking $f$ in to odd/even piecewise to do proofs with it.

Comment: Which is what I did with my $n=2k+a$ thing there. If a=1, you add 1. If a=0, you don't add anything.

Answer (score 2):

Claim: if $\alpha: A\to B$ is a bijection and $\beta:B\to C$ is a bijection, $\gamma:A\to C$ given by $\gamma:=\beta\circ \alpha$ is a bijection. This allows us to make 'pit stops', i.e. to construct the bijection one map at a time.

To go from $\mathbb{Z}^+\to \mathbb{Z}$, one way is send $n$ to $(n+1)/2$ if $n$ is odd (this will map into $\mathbb{Z}^+$) and to send $n$ to $(2-n)/2$ if $n$ is even (this will map into $\mathbb{Z}^-\cup \{0\}$).

Now that we're in $\mathbb{Z}$, we can 'delete zero' from the range by sending $n$ to $n+1$ if $n\ge 0$ and otherwise sending $n$ to itself (i.e., leaving it untouched).

I will leave it to you to extend this to deleting the other two points and to come up with a closed-form, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we denote $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{-1,0,1\} \{x \in \mathbb{Z} : x \neq -1,0,1\}$, i.e. the set of integers excluding $-1,0,1$. Although $\mathbb{Z}$ has "more" elements than $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{-1,0,1\}$, these sets in fact have the same cardinality, i.e. they have the same "size" in a set-theoretic sense. Having the same cardinality is equivalent to the existence of a bijection between the two sets, which is what you are asked to prove.

Here is a function. Define $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{-1,0,1\}$ such that $\phi(x) = x + 2$ if $x \geq 0$, and $\phi(x) = x - 1$ if $x < 0$. $\phi$ is a bijection.

EDIT: I misread $\mathbb{Z}^+$ as $\mathbb{Z}$. @GS1221 You seemed to correctly identify a bijection in your comments, mapping $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to $2,-2,3,-3,...$ successively. Define $\phi : \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{-1,0,1\}$ s.t. $\phi(1) = 2$, $\phi(2) = -2$, $\phi(3) = 3$, $\phi(4) = -3$, and so on. This can be formalized as $\phi(x) = 1 + \frac{x + 1}{2}$ if $x$ is odd, and $\phi(x) = -(1 + \frac{x}{2})$ if $x$ is even.

Comment: $\mathbb Z\neq\mathbb Z^+$

Comment: I have to go from Z+ not Z, otherwise that is perfect

Comment: @Angelica Ah, you're right. Let me correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Despite appearances, the sets are the same size.

I am going to assume that the positive integers does not include zero (as opposed to the non-negative integers).

And rather than thinking about how to map the positive integers to the integers excluding $\{-1,0,1\}$. I am going to map the integers excluding $\{-1,0,1\}$ to the positive integers.  And, since it will be a bijection, an inverse map exists.

Map the positive numbers of the set to the even positive integers.  $2$ maps to $2, 3$ maps to $4, n$ maps to $2n-1$ if $n\ge 1$

And map the negative numbers to the odd positive integers.  $n = 2n-3$ if $n\le -2$

And, I will leave it to you to work out the inverse map.

Comment: With respect, I don't see what this adds to the three existing answers.